# Найти записи в которых время начала и конца поползает в интервал предыдущей записи

Tags: java, база-данных

Таблица такая:

```
create table test_interval (
start_i int not null,
end_i int not null,
constraint end_gte_start check (end_i>=start_i)
);
```

`Start_i` и `End_i` это время начала интервала и его конец.

**Задача:** найти записи в которых время начала и конца поползает в интервал предыдущей записи. (Надеюсь понятно объяснил) найдя такие записи из нужно удалить и вместо них добавить одну по такой формуле:

```
R3.start_i=min(R1.start_i, R2.start_i)
R3.end_i =max(R1.end_i, R2.end_i)
```

т.е. найти минимальное и максимальное время начала и конца интервала.

В таблице могут быть большое количество данных (записей). Этот код должен бежать раз в какое то время и в случае если БД не отвечает (внизу) нужно оповестить пользователя. Но вопрос мой о том каким образом лучше реализовать такой функционал?

Так как данных может быть много может лучше читать «пакетами» (частями) и в случае если в процессе упадёт база у меня останутся какие то данные которые я успел прочитать. Но в этом случае мне нужно будет прочитанную часть где то хранить, где лучше это сделать?

Или может использовать джава транзакции как второй вариант? И тогда если база упадёт произойдёт ролбек. Может есть ещё вариант?

Comment: Конечная то задача какая? "Много" - это сколько? Завалить БД - это надо очень постараться. `БД не отвечает (внизу)` - в каком, извините, низу?

Comment: @rjhdby а том самом низу server down видимо :D

Comment: сервер внизу, время вверх, мертвый замок, пузырение событий и так далее

Comment: Да внизу это как раз server down :-)  Много это миллион например.

Comment: @tarasula миллион записей - это не тот объем, по поводу которого стоит переживать. Любая современная БД на любом железе потянет в легкую.

Comment: Ну а все же какую реализацию для данной задачи посоветовали бы?

Comment: укажите, что у вас за база и добавьте соответствующие метки, может кто-то предложит решение на sql или хранимых процедурах.